# com_exception with message Source: Unknown Description: Unknown IIS PHP

Tags: php, com, iis-8

I'm using a VM deployed with windows server r2 2012 and facing an issue while converting PPT to Image using PHP COM dll on IIS8.Below is the code that I'm using

```
 <?php 
    $file_path = "test_ppt_to_image.pptx";
    $powerpnt = new COM("powerpoint.application") or die("");
    try {
        $presentation = $powerpnt->Presentations->Open(realpath($file_path)) or die("Unable to open the slide");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";exit;
    }
    $i=1;
    $exportFolder = realpath("test_images");
    foreach($presentation->Slides as $slide)
    {
        $slideName =  $i."_SS_";
        $slide->Export($exportFolder."/".$slideName.".jpg", "jpg");
    $i++;
    }
    $powerpnt->quit();
    ?>
```

below is the error from catch

```
Error : [13-Apr-2016 23:43:30 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: Unknown
Description: Unknown' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ppttoimage.php:5
Stack trace:
0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ppttoimage.php(5): variant->Open('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ppttoimage.php on line 5
```

I tried giving permissions from command "dcomcnfg" for DCOM extensions and no luck still getting the same error.

**Can anyone plz help me with some solution. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did you sort it finally?